# Rearranging data from a single column

Tags: vba, excel

I require help in writing a code for Excel VBA. I have data in the following format:

```
12.12312
ser-asd alskdja123 alskd bv
laskd alskdj alsdj
12.423
12.656
asd sdfgsd sdfsd sdfsdf
sdfsd sd fsd fsd fsdf
```

**Current data is stored in a single Excel column**. I want to be in the following format :

```
12.12312      ser-asd alskdja123 alskd bv      laskd alskdj alsdj
12.423
12.656        ser-asd alskdja123 alskd bv      sdfsd sd fsd fsd fsdf
```

I am not a high level programmer, I am a networks engineer.

Comment: Please post the code (you can edit your question) that you have worked on so that we can help you! ;)

Comment: Are you having trouble with the [For ...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)? Always start at the bottom and work to the top when deleting rows. Maybe the reverse split to keep the strings in order across the columns? Use a variant array.

Comment: Are there some typos between the last two string values in the sample data and the two strings shown in the last row of the sample results?

Comment: What is the logic behind replacing the line after 12.656 with the line after 12.12312

Comment: Someone finally got the title spelled correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You will be removing rows after collecting the strings from column A; always start at the bottom and work to the top when deleting rows. Collecting the strings into a delimited list (using a zero-length space as the delimiter in the following case) allows you to directly [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) the string into the target cells using the [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) to [.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) the destination.

```
Sub urgent()
    Dim rw As Long, str As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<~~ set this worksheet reference properly!
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(rw, "A")) Then
                If CBool(Len(str)) Then
                    .Cells(rw, "B").Resize(1, UBound(Split(str, ChrW(8203)))) = _
                        Split(str, ChrW(8203))
                End If
                str = vbNullString
            Else
                str = .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 & ChrW(8203) & str
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
        For v = .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Columns(v).AutoFit
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

This routine does depend upon the fact that the values you've listed are in column A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what is actually required from such input is:

[image: SO33607094 example]

without the shaded rows. This is achievable without VBA, provided a number terminates the list, such as with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISNUMBER($A1),NOT(ISNUMBER(OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-1,)))),IF(A1<>"",OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-1,),""),OFFSET($A1,COLUMN(),-1,)),"")
```

in B1 copied down to suit and then all formulae across until a column is blank throughout.

The shaded rows may be deleted by 'fixing' the formulae results (copy all cells and Paste Special..., Values over the top) and filtering to delete rows that are blank in ColumnB.

Assumes the likes of `12.12312` is indeed a number, not text.

Comment: ... or filtering to delete rows that are blank in Column B.